# Getting characters and converting them into string

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

static int cc =0;
static FILE* in;

static char* getkw(){
    char tok[10];
    int i;
    cc = fgetc(in);
    for(i=0; i<=(int)sizeof(tok)-1 &&isalpha(cc);++i){
        tok[i]= cc;
        cc = fgetc(in);
    }                    
    tok[i]=0;
    return tok;
}

int main()
{
    in = fopen("/dir/dir/a.txt", "r");
    char *c= getkw();
    printf("%s", c);
    fclose(in);
    return 0;
}
```

I've expected above code to get characters till space is reached. Also I have functions that ignore spaces from file and continue to next character which I've not shohwn here because they are (in my view) working well. The main problem here is, it doesn't get a character from file and doesn't pack them into array. The program crashes or nothing appears (if success).

Comment: you can't return tok

Comment: char* tok = malloc(10);

Comment: Your indentation was weird. Did you like how your code looked? Or did you mix tabs and blanks, that easily messes up the indentation.

Comment: The problem with `tok` is that you allocate it on the stack, and when the function returns, you can't rely on its contents anymore. One way is to allocate `tok` dynamically, as @purec hints at.

Comment: Why is `cc` a global variable?  Why isn't it local to the `getkw()` function?  If you did `ungetc(c, fp);` you'd be able to reread the character after the keyword.  As it is, you just throw that character away because you set `cc` unconditionally when you call `getkw()` again.

Comment: A likely problem is that the code fails to open the file but then crashes because your code does not check that the file was opened.  You simply cannot afford not to check that the file was opened; there are far too many ways for it to fail.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler this is a sample taken from my original code (cc is decared a gobal because its used by different functions within the project and will become unavailable for other functions if i declare it locally.

Comment: In that case, it is a toss-up between "returning a pointer to a local variable" and "didn't check the result of opening the file" which is causing the problem.  It should be easy for you to eliminate the file issue; that would leave the other as the source of your trouble.  (Both need to be fixed to get somewhere near production-quality code.)

Comment: Another possible problem: You state that it should get characters until space is encountered. However, it also quits whenever anything other than a letter occurs - for example, a period, or a comma, or a numeral, or any character that is not in [a-zA-Z]

Answer (score 2):

Returning a pointer to a local variable will not work, because the array is no longer in scope. It is `tok` which should be `static` not the function.

There is another bug following

```
for(i=0; i<=(int)sizeof(tok)-1 &&isalpha(cc);++i)
```

which would be clearer if the condition is written as the more idiomatic

```
i<(int)sizeof(tok)
```

which is less work for the brain. Now it is clear that

```
tok[i]=0;
```

after the loop, when `i == sizeof tok`, is writing beyond the array bounds.

---

**Edit:** more generally about loop control.

There is another danger with your `-1` way of doing things. Suppose I use your way in

```
size_t len = strlen(tok);
for(size_t i = 0; i <= len - 1; i++) { /*...*/ }
```

What will happen when `len == 0`?
Disaster, because `size_t` is unsigned, and so `len - 1` will wrap to the max value for the type, and there will be a huge loop.

Now, if you write the loop in the idiomatic way

```
size_t len = strlen(tok);
for(size_t i = 0; i < len; i++) { /*...*/ }
```

this cannot happen.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that in the function `getkw()` the array `tok` is a local variable, so the memory is freed when the function returns. Thus, the pointer you're trying to return becomes invalid and the program crashes when you try to print it.

To solve the problem you will either have to dynamically allocate memory with `malloc` and return the pointer, or pass a pointer to the array into the function and modify it.

For dynamic memory allocation:

```
char* tok = malloc(10);
```

For passing a pointer to array:

```
static void getkw(char[] * array){
    char[] tok = * array;
    ...
    //no need to return anything, since you modify the passed array
}

int main()
{
    char tok[10];
    getkw(&tok);
    ...
}
```